# Get row count in MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql-python

Is there a better way to get the row count than doing the following?

```
cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT(provider_id) FROM main_iteminstance")
num_items = len(cursor.fetchall())
```

Is there a shorthand in `MySQLdb` for the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could execute the following SQL directly on cursor.execute rather than depending on MySQLdb:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT provider_id) FROM main_iteminstance")
```

Then you just get the result from that query.

Answer (score 2):

The result of cursor.execute returns the number of rows returned by the query so just assign to a variable.

```
num_items = cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT(provider_id) FROM main_iteminstance")
```

This will also work and you won't have to run an extra query just to get the number of items